# Can't find path to Image in pictureBox,Image = new Bitmap(path)

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I need to load a picture to a pictureBox in a WindowsCE 6.0 . When I run the program in the mobile it tells me that it can't find the path.
This is my code:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@" Data Source = \Program Files\Data\Image20120523_1.jpeg ");
```

I already tried with this paths to but it doesn't work:

> path1: @"\Program Files\Data\Image20120523_1.jpeg"
>   path2: "\Program Files\Data\Image20120523_1.jpeg"

I have a database located in the same path and when I use it to make the connection it works ok, why it isn't working to load the image?

**SOLUTION**
This path works ok:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"\Program Files\Data\Image20120523_1.jpeg");
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Well you definitely shouldn't have 'Data Source =' within the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use simple path to the image file here. Like this:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"E:\temp\photo\IMG_1461.JPG");
```

Comment: I already tried with that path but it doesn't work. I have my picture in this path: Program Files\Data\Myphoto.jpg, as it is in a mobile I can't the path like "E:". I found that I must put something like Data Source = path. Any more ideas? Thanks!